# Parse.com - Request from cloud to database is considered as one request?

Tags: parse-platform

As example if I write one cloud method, and call inside it 5 request to database. When I have called this method from client it will be 6 or 5 or 1 request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to a Cloud Function or the Database counts as an API request, regardless of the source.

It would count as 6 API hits.